# React Native Increment State onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to learning React / React Native and have run into the following issue. When tapping on the `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` element, the view does not increment.

Code below:

```
class SingleHabit extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {count: 0};
  }

  _incrementCount() {
    this.setState = ({
      count: count + 1
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => this._incrementCount() }>
        <View
          style= {[
            styles.singleHabit,
            {backgroundColor: this.props.color}
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.habitNameText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.countText}>{this.state.count}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, in the interest of self-learning, if there's anyway you would refactor this (or just simply better ways of doing things), I'd love to hear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` inside your incrementCount function isn't automatically bound to the class. If you change it to use arrow functions, then the scope of `this` becomes the class. Also its good practice to use the optional function setState if you want to modify state based offa previous state values:

```
   _incrementCount = () => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! + thanks for the good practice advice :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `_incrementCount` function is wrong.

- You are not calling `this.setState` never. You are assign `({count: count + 1})` to `this.setState`. Correct it removing the `=`.
- The `count` used in the expression `count + 1` is not defined. Change it to `this.state.count`.

.

Summarizing, Change

```
   _incrementCount() {
     this.setState = ({
       count: count + 1
     });
   }
```

to

```
  _incrementCount() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }
```